# sbt build failure in jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, guava

I am trying to build my project after upgrading to scala 2.12 and sbt 1.3.2. The build is successful in local but failing in my jenkins pipeline. One of the dependency is resolved but not available during compile time. Here are the details

The error I am seeing in jenkins pipeline is

```
[error] /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/scala-app/src/main/scala/com/org/project/utils/JavaHelper.scala:5:8:
        object FutureCallback is not a member of package com.google.common.util.concurrent
[error] import com.google.common.util.concurrent.{FutureCallback, Futures, ListenableFuture}
```

The associated library is `"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "26.0-android"`.
This dependency is obtained indirectly which I have validated through `dependencyTree` command.

scala: `2.12.15`

sbt: `1.3.2`

I even tried declaring the dependency explicitly in `build.sbt` however the issue still persists. I have tried the build in a clean environment as well (docker container) and it was success.

I am unable to figure out what could be the cause for this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try sbt 1.3.13, perhaps? If you're not able to move to an even newer version, I mean. (Latest is 1.6.2.)

Comment: It's really hard for us to even guess at what the problem might be, since we have no information about what might be different about your Jenkins setup (the broken one) versus your other two setups (the working one). You might try comparing the full logs of the three runs with a diff tool. (And if info-level logging shows no relevant differences, try debug-level logging.)